# ImageView load from URL with Picasso does not ALWAYS fit full screen width

Tags: android

I have a problem with ImageView load from URL with Picasso library because it does not ALWAYS fit full screen width (it is the requirement for the app). Some of such loaded graphics DOES fit the width of the screen and some DOES NOT. I can not understand why sometimes it is not full width streached.

My code fragment related to ImageView and Picasso load:

```
ImageView imgURL = new ImageView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsImgURL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsImgURL.setMargins(0,45,0,5);
paramsImgURL.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
imgURL.setLayoutParams(paramsImgURL);
imgURL.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imgURL.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Picasso.get().load(uRL).into(imgURL);

holder.layout.addView(imgURL);
```

My dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Possibly you have some transparent margins in some of the images.

Comment: Thank you but I don't. All margins are the same